# Extract the date from url and update the database

Tags: sql-server

Table consists of the site url and the published date.

I want to extract the date from the URL and update to the corresponding column.

While extracting the date from the document there were exception and it could not extract the date from the some of the document. However, some column have the properly formatted date.

I wanted to update all the row having the date as `01/01/0001`, by extracting the date from the url.

I have data in this format:

```
PublishedDate                | Id     | Href
-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |20700   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10502/2019-04-04
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |20730   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10931/2019-04-09
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |20884   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/11632/2019-04-17
2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |23016   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1861/2019-01-01
2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |22980   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1839/2019-01-01
2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |22981   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1826/2019-01-01
2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000  |22988   |https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1782/2019-01-01
```

I am stuck at how to extract the date from the url.

Please help.

Comment: Take a look at [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Is actual published date field VARCHAR or is it stored as a date-type datatype?

Comment: @RossBush it's as datetime2.

Comment: I have to ask....why are you storing datetime information in a column that is obviously not using a datetime datatype because it has invalid values. You should use the proper datatype for the data being stored. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Currently my application is dumping all the data while scraping from the websites i am not sure if there may be some exception during the insertion. so, to be safe and avoid any error during the conversion on the .net API. 
may be this is not the valid explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  Here we are using a `patindex()`

**Example**

```
Update YourTable
 Set  PublishedDate = substring(Href,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',Href),10)
 Where Try_convert(date,[PublishedDate]) is null
```

**The Updated Table**

```
PublishedDate   Id  Href
2019-04-04  20700   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10502/2019-04-04
2019-04-09  20730   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10931/2019-04-09
2019-04-17  20884   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/11632/2019-04-17
2019-01-01  23016   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1861/2019-01-01
2019-01-01  22980   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1839/2019-01-01
2019-01-01  22981   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1826/2019-01-01
2019-01-01  22988   https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1782/2019-01-01
```

> **EDIT - To Update only the invalid records**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,URLDate = substring(Href,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',Href),10)
     From  YourTable
)
Update cte
 Set  PublishedDate = URLDate
 Where left(PublishedDate,10) <> URLDate
```

In this option, only the top 3 records would be updated

Comment: I think it will update all the rows, but is there a way to update only those rows which doesn't have the proper date.

Comment: @AkshayKriti sure give me a moment

Answer (score 2):

Just as another way of skinning this cat. Here I am using PARSENAME. Since it is limited to only 4 elements I simply removed the first part of the URL through the domain. Then replace the remaining slashes with periods so PARSENAME will work.

```
update YourTable
set PublishedDate = parsename(replace(replace(Href, 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/', ''), '/', '.'), 1)
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti LOL it isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
with test (Href) as
(SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10502/2019-04-04' UNION
SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10931/2019-04-09'  UNION
SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/11632/2019-04-17' UNION
SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1861/2019-01-01' UNION
SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1839/2019-01-01' UNION
SELECT 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/1782/2019-01-01')

UPDATE yourTABLE 
SET PublishedDate  = CAST(SUBSTRING(href,LEN(href) - CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(href)) + 2,LEN(href)) as date)
FROM test
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use a combination of SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions

below is an example.. Change variable with your field name

```
declare @a varchar(1000) = 'https://nayapatrikadaily.com/news-details/10502/2019-04-04'
select SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/2019', @a) + 1, 100)
```

Comment: What happens in 2020 ?

Comment: True.. any suggestions? @JohnCappelletti

Comment: Just posted a patindex() option.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Good answer. Can you explain why [0-9] appears 8 times?

Comment: We are looking for a pattern ####-##-##   actually (for example) the MONTH could be [0-1][0-9]  to be more precise

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks for the explanation